# dynamically input year based on date range

Tags: php

I have an application that is good from September 1st of the current year, and ends January 15th of the following year.

What I need to do is enter the current year into the database when they submit their application.

If the user completes the application between Sept 1, 2012 and January 15, 2013 - 2012 will be entered into the table.

Say it is January 2, 2013 - it will enter 2012 into the year column

Say it is November 10, 2012 - it will enter 2012 into the year column

Say it is December 5, 2013 - it will enter 2013 into the year column.

I can't wrap my head around how I will be able to insert the appropriate year (in this situation anyway).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So there is a grace period of 15 days after the new year?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: If you extend all three sentences you list over there like: *"Say it is January 2, 2013 - it will enter 2012 into the year column **because ...**"*. If you do that, I think this will help you to wrap the head around it better.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `if` `else` statement work? simply check the current date, it it's within the threshold, year = 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're giving yourself a grace period of 15 days after the new year. When the user submits the form capture the date and year. If the date is between January 1st and January 15th then substract 1 from your current year, if not use the current year.

Something like:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$year = date('Y');

if( $date >= date('Y-01-01') && $date <= date('Y-01-15') ) {
  $year--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = time();
$date1 = strtotime('9/1/2012');
$date2 = strtotime('1/15/2012');
$currentYear = '';
if ($today < $date1) {
    $currentYear = '2011';
}
else if ($today < $date2) {
    $currentYear = '2012';
}
else {
    $currentYear = '2013';
}
```

That is obviously not dynamic for future years and makes some assumptions about what you want to do when it is less than 9/1/2012, but hopefully this gets you started.